# Challenge returning an array in a Ruby Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, debugging

I'm having a challenge returning an array. For the `def won?(board)` method, I'm trying to return the array in the 0 index position [0,1,2] when the if conditional is met. so I have it say: return [0,1,2]

BUT! When I run the code through the editor, I get this error message:

```
returns an array of matching indexes for a top row win (FAILED - 3)
```

and the test provides this error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(won?(board)).to match_array([0,1,2])
  NoMethodError:
   undefined method `won?' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::LibGameStatusRb::Won:0x007f82d3b26508>
  # ./spec/game_status_spec.rb:35:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have provided the code below, along with the array. I've tried using puts or just having the array included and neither work. Any suggestions you might have are greatly appreciated!

```
WIN_COMBINATIONS = [
 [0,1,2],
 [0,3,6],
 [0,4,8],
 [1,4,7],
 [2,5,8],
 [3,4,5],
 [6,7,8],
 [6,4,2]  
] 

top_row_win = WIN_COMBINATIONS[0]
middle_row_win = WIN_COMBINATIONS[5]
bottom_row_win = WIN_COMBINATIONS[6]
left_column_win = WIN_COMBINATIONS[1]
middle_column_win = WIN_COMBINATIONS[3]
right_column_win = WIN_COMBINATIONS[4]
left_diagonal_win = WIN_COMBINATIONS[2]
right_diagonal_win = WIN_COMBINATIONS[7]

def won?(board) 
   if board[top_row_win[0]] == "X" && board[top_row_win[1]] == "X" && board[top_row_win[2]] == "X"
 return [0,1,2]
  else false
end 
end
```

Comment: You are calling won? rather than won - either change the method you're calling in your test or the name of the method in your code. Some people didn't consider that to be an answer to this question so I'm putting it as a comment and will refrain from pointing out basic errors in the future

Comment: def won? doesn't work either though.

Answer (score 0):

This has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with returning an array. In fact, as the error message very clearly tells you, it couldn't even find the method, and if it can't find the method, then obviously the method will never be called, and if the method is never called, then basic logic tells us that it is completely and utterly irrelevant what's inside the method, including what it returns.

> ```
> NoMethodError: undefined method `won?' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::LibGameStatusRb::Won:0x007f82d3b26508>
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

It didn't find any method named `won?`, so it cannot possibly have executed the method you defined, so its return value cannot possibly be relevant to your problem.

Your problem is that your method isn't being found, you need to figure out why that is the case, instead of focusing on the array.

Comment: as i stated in the comments above i changed the method and that made no difference. please be more circumspect in reading the comments in the future before down voting a question, if that's what occurred.